# Why do I not have to forward declare functions or variables inside classes?

Tags: c++, function, class, variables, c++11

Original question can be found below.

So, we found out that the following doesn't work:

```
void f(){
    g();
}
void g(){}
```

But, it **does** work inside a class, and that's where I got confused:

```
class test{
   int getY(){
       return getX();
   }
   int getX(){
       return 10;
   }
}
```

This compiles perfectly fine under MSVC10.0.

[Ideone link. It does work.](http://ideone.com/YlwL8G)

So, after rephrasing, the question is:

*Why do I not need forward declaration inside a class?*

#### Original question, please ignore

In C++, the order in which functions or variables are declared does not matter at all. There is nothing wrong with calling functions that are not declared yet. The same applies for variables:

But, it doesn't work for classes. If I want to use a class that is defined later in a source-file, I have to forward declare it.

*Why? What prevents the compiler from knowing all class declarations?*

Comment: "There is nothing wrong with calling functions that are not declared yet." I think you might want to double-check that one. ;)

Comment: Classes need to have a size before they're used so the thing using them knows how much to allocate. A forward declaration leaves it as an incomplete type. Functions are simple - the linker finds the definition if it's not inlined or something. Variables... I'm not quite sure what you're referencing but same thing. Doing `extern int i;` has a clear size - `sizeof(int)` - but no definition (yet).

Comment: @dlf I can write `void f(){ g() } void g(){}`, right?

Comment: @iFreilicht: Provided you have a declaration `void g();` above `void f()`, then yes. But you need to have it declared first.

Comment: @iFreilicht But you *can* write `void g(); void f(){ g(); } void g(){}`. There *may* be an exception or two, but in general, the C++ compiler is not able to "read ahead" to figure out what a symbol means.

Comment: @iFreilicht; http://ideone.com/zLV17w

Comment: @iFreilicht - You may be confused because if you `declare` a class in a header file and then `implement` the class in a file that includes the header you may implement them in any order and use non-implemented functions. However you have to remember that they are ALL `declared` in the header file.

Comment: @haccks interesting. I've added an example that compiles under MSVC10.0

Comment: @iFreilicht Your update shows a special case, and makes the question interesting. +1 from me.

Comment: Declaring a class, including all members, is one statement (hence the ending semicolon which you forgot).  The entire declaration is in scope for itself regardless of the order in which members are presented.

Comment: @dlf I should've written the question like that in the first place, probably.

Comment: @iFreilicht It's not too late to edit the title to indicate you're focused on member functions defined inside the class definition. You might still get a downvote or two cancelled that way.

Comment: Your example with _classes_: http://ideone.com/34cmqc.

Comment: Further to the "within the same full statement" idea, something like `int a = a;`, while nonsensical, does not produce an "undeclared identifier" error: http://ideone.com/6BazZS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In C++, the order in which functions or variables are declared does
>   not matter at all. There is nothing wrong with calling functions that
>   are not declared yet. The same applies for variables.

... That's not at all true? You need to declare functions and variables before using them, otherwise the compiler will not be particularly happy with you.

**EDIT** In response to the edit, what you have shown is a very special case in which everything involved is internal to a class. In this particular case, you can use undeclared variable and function names. The only reason you can do this is because the compiler treats the class definition as one unit and reads through all of it before compiling. In general, however, you have to forward declare everything.

Comment: ...happy with you ;p  +1

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing. Thanks for the edit, I got it now.

Comment: Note that there is nothing special about _functions_ in his special case. _Variables_ could also be used first (inside the body of a member function) and declared later inside the same class declaration.

Comment: [It seems to work with classes, too.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122870/why-do-i-not-have-to-forward-declare-functions-or-variables-inside-classes?noredirect=1#comment37218100_24122870)

Answer (score 2):

In general, every name must be declared before use, whether they name classes, function, variables, or whatever.

However, there is a special case: within (most of) a class definition, you can use names of members of that class even if they haven't been declared yet. The example you added demonstrates this, and would still work if the undeclared name was of a class, variable or whatever, as long is it was a member of `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaration of classes is something like specifying prototype of function.

In this manner, you can specify class name without currently mentioning its content similar to function prototype where you can specify function signature to declare its scope before specifying its definition. 
The definition can be done after certain piece of code.

Yes, to this there is an exception i.e. members included within classes or structures. These members have same scope.